# A custom post within a custom post

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

### Design

I am trying to design 2 custom post types that have a relationship.
The models are basically menus and dishes, it's a 'one to many' relationship where the dishes 'belong to' the menu.

- In every menu post there are dishes post.
- dishes in menus are saved for future use of that menu.

## UI

- UI shows 3 types of menus.
- Admin chooses which 3 menu posts to show from all the menu posts he created.
- In every menu post there are dishes post.

## Issue

I am not familiar with creating a custom post loop within another custom post loop I tried googling for this but the question itself is a bit tricky.

Care to share how you would build this type of relationship on WP?
Thanks,
Bud.

Comment: I don't know if you have already started coding, but the easiest way to work with custom posts is to use the [ACF plugin](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) - then when you have the relation set up, you have the assigned posts ("dishes" in your case) easily available as one of the fields of the "menu" custom post.

Comment: @Picard thanks for the reply sport, yes I do code but normally in native or within another framework (Laravel). I'm also familiar with ACF and used it in a few projects, but if your referring to ACF, at least tell me how you managed to take one post object repeater and put another post object repeating in it. Would a `subfield` as a post object work?

Comment: I would rather see the 'dishes' posts as a [relationship field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/) within the 'menu' post type.

Comment: @Picard it's in the #design in my op. 
*it's a 'one to many' relationship where the dishes 'belong to' the menu*